# Sort array [[String: Any]] alphabetically in Swift 3.0

Tags: arrays, swift3

As I am new in Swift, I want to do sorting on **cityName** key.

```
var arrCityList: [[String: Any]] = []
```

CityList:

```
[["pk_cityID": 1, "cityName": Ahmedabad], ["pk_cityID": 25, "cityName": Dahod], ["pk_cityID": 39, "cityName": Antah], ["pk_cityID": 44, "cityName": Bahror], ["pk_cityID": 117, "cityName": Jahazpur]]
```

`arrCityList` contains the **CityList** kind of data.

I have done lots of **SOF** but I didn't find answer for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try

```
var arrCityList: [[String: Any]] = [["pk_cityID": 1, "cityName": "Ahmedabad"], ["pk_cityID": 25, "cityName": "Dahod"], ["pk_cityID": 39, "cityName": "Antah"], ["pk_cityID": 44, "cityName": "Bahror"], ["pk_cityID": 117, "cityName": "Jahazpur"]]

arrCityList.sort { ($0["cityName"] as! String) < ($1["cityName"] as! String) }

print(arrCityList)
```

Comment: Thanks. bit delay due to work.

Comment: @Himanshupadia no worries at all :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var arrCityList = [[String: Any]]()

arrCityList.append(["pk_cityID": 1, "cityName": "Ahmedabad"])
arrCityList.append(["pk_cityID": 25, "cityName": "Dahod"])
arrCityList.append(["pk_cityID": 39, "cityName": "Antah"])
arrCityList.append(["pk_cityID": 44, "cityName": "Bahror"])
arrCityList.append(["pk_cityID": 117, "cityName": "Jahazpur"])


arrCityList.sort {
  let cityNameA = $0.0["cityName"] as! String
  let cityNameB = $0.1["cityName"] as! String

  return cityNameA < cityNameB
}


print(arrCityList)
// [
//   ["pk_cityID": 1, "cityName": "Ahmedabad"], 
//   ["pk_cityID": 39, "cityName": "Antah"], 
//   ["pk_cityID": 44, "cityName": "Bahror"], 
//   ["pk_cityID": 25, "cityName": "Dahod"], 
//   ["pk_cityID": 117, "cityName": "Jahazpur"], 
//   ["pk_cityID": 117, "cityName": "Jahazpur"]
// ]
```

Comment: Thanks. works as expected.